# Configuring the registers of i2c AD converter ADS122C04

Tags: i2c, adc, wire-library

I am not able to set the configuration registers of the TI´s converter chip ADS122C04 using arduino MEGA via I2C.

The code mainly consists of the following:

1-reset the chip (one byte)

2-choose register (WREG) and set register data (figure 59 of the data sheet) for all four registers

3- start conversion (one byte)

In sum, ten (10) bytes are sent in one i2c frame using an array of bytes as follows:

```
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------

int ADR_THeiz_Austritt = 0x40;                                  //hex Adress of the device 

byte InitArray[10] = {6, 64, 54, 68, 10, 72, 5, 76, 112, 8};    //configuration array



 Wire.beginTransmission(ADR_THeiz_Austritt);            //  talk to Slave

 Wire.write(InitArray,10);             // bytes array is sent to slave on ACK handshaking           

  status = Wire.endTransmission();     //status as in 
                              //https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireEndTransmission

  Serial.print("Status Initialisierung = ");

  Serial.println(status);
```

//--------------------------------------------------------------------

status is a byte, which indicates the status of the transmission:

0:success

1:data too long to fit in transmit buffer

2:received NACK on transmit of address

3:received NACK on transmit of data

4:other error

after configuration, when reading the value of e.g. register 0, the result was 0 (default) !!

A second attempt was performed with a for loop

```
     //--------------------------------------------------------------------

      for (int i=0; i<10; i++)

  {

    Wire.beginTransmission(ADR_THeiz_Austritt);

    Wire.write(InitArray[i]);                                                      

    //delay(10);

  status = Wire.endTransmission();                                       

  Serial.print("status Initialisierung ");

  Serial.print(i);                      //print the array element no

      Serial.println(status);          //print the status of transmision

      }

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

the print function outputs the following: 00, 10, 23, 30,43,50,63,70,83,90 which means:

i=0, InitArray[i]=6, status =0 --> Reset of chip successfull

i=1, InitArray[i]=64, status =0 --> adressing Register 0 successfull

i=2, InitArray[i]=54, status =3 -->  value for Register 0 not transmitted !! (the same applies for all registers)

i=9, InitArray[i]=8, status =0 --> start chip successfull

My question: why am I not able to put a value in the registers? what am I doing wrong?

would appreciate your support!